# Rails 3 - Devise user not clearing notice tag

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-1.9.2

I have an user managed by Devise. I am managing this user in my own views, creating a new user, or updating the existing ones.

I have the following tag in my layout:

```
<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
```

The problem is that when I update an user, I receive the message "Your account has been updated" (which I want to change). After pressing the link to go back to the Users index the notice is still there. It doesn't clear.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should check your respond_to block in your method, and if the notice is set as a flash notice, you can also manually delete the array of flash message.

```
flash.delete(:notice)
```

The following link might be helpful:
[Devise - Flash Notices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139222/devise-flash-notices)